# Make nested content inside Bootstrap 4 column scrollable

Tags: bootstrap-4, scroll, flexbox

I want a nested content (inside column) to be scrollable, without the entire window to be scrollable.

[image]

The below example almost work, but the whole content doesn't fit 100% of the viewport height, thus a scrollbar appear on the right, which is bad.

http://jsfiddle.net/7zxq64d3/1/

The CSS part :

```
    #leftCol {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    #subcontent {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
      min-height: 0px;
    }
```

100vh sounds wrong, but :

- if I don't set the height to a defined value, scrollable subcontent won't scroll
- header and subheader have unknown height, so I can't set a fixed-value height to the left column.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me on Reddit. Here is it's solution, it works well with Bootstrap also :

https://codepen.io/pigparlor/pen/NWbBMYL

Here is the SCSS part :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  &__header {
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
  }
  
  &__content {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.columns {
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  
  &__item {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

.sub-content {
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  &__header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
  
  &__text {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

The problem was tougher to solve than I initially thought. But now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It was an interesting problem to solve (as I’m sure @bdavidxyz found as well). I had time to play and I wanted to see if I could get the effect using Bootstrap-4 classes.

Your initial example showed the content close to the left and right side, but on a large display, that looked strange, so I used the Bootstrap container to limit the maximum width of the content to 1140px (both container and container-fluid version are below).

Because the way the columns are arranged, I don’t think there’s a way to reorganize the screen for small screens, so I limited the body width to at least 480px.

The contained version:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body style="min-width: 480px;">
    <div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row  bg-dark text-light">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Varying height header - contained version</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden">
            <div class="row d-flex overflow-hidden">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden h-100">
                    <div class="bg-primary text-light px-3 pt-2">
                        <h3>Subheader</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-success text-light px-3 pt-2" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                        <h3>Scrollable subcontent</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
                        
                        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="px-3 pt-2">
                        <h3>Right column</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the full width version:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body style="min-width: 480px;">
    <div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row  bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Varying height header - full width version</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-grow-1 d-flex overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <div class="bg-primary text-light px-3 pt-2">
                    <h2>Subheader</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-success text-light px-3 pt-2" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <h2>Scrollable subcontent</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
                    
                    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 h-100 overflow-hidden">
                <div class="px-3 pt-2">
                    <h3>Right column</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fantastic solution, without external CSS, and minimalist inline-style. Thanks !